# When is an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process equivalent to Brownian motion up to a given time lag

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

## Background

The expected displacement under the assumption of Brownian Motion for time step $\tau$ is given by $$\gamma(\tau) = D|\tau|$$ where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient.

If one assumes a 'pull back' mechanism to some point of attraction, the diffusion up to a given $\tau$ can be modeled with an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, with the expected displacement after $\tau$ time steps is given by $$\gamma(\tau) = \sigma \left(1 - \exp \left(-\frac{|\tau|}{\tau_m}\right) \right)$$ where $\sigma$ is the distance from 0 where the 'pull back' starts and $\tau_m$ the time lag at which the 'pull back' starts.

Further, if $\sigma \to \infty$ and $\tau_m \to \infty$ then an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is equivalent to Brownian motion with $D = \frac{\sigma}{\tau_m}$.

## Question

Now my question: Is it possible to say for which $\sigma$ and $\tau_m$ there is no difference between an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and Brownian motion up to a given time lag $\tau$.

Comment: I would say, for no finite nonzero values of $\sigma$ and $\tau_m$. But you should explain precisely what you mean by "there is no difference".

Comment: I am fitting both processes to data and would like to come up with a measure to say when it is appropriate to choose Brownian Motion over the more complex Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

Comment: Then the question concerns the data, not the properties of these two theoretical models.